# Does Thread.sleep(milis) function make all Threads sleep?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I have a code fragment from a "Runnable" class is like that:

```
public void run() {
    //Do some stuff
    while(!someCondition){      
        //Do some stuff
        while(anotherCondition){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Do some stuff
        }
        threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        RunnableClass rc = new RunnableClass();
        Thread rcThread = new Thread(rc);
        rcThread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new SomeUncaughtExHandler());
        threadExecutor.execute(rcThread);
    }
    //Do some stuff     
}
```

Does calling `Thread.sleep(60000);` cause all of RunnableClass Threads to sleep or not?

Comment: Only the current thread.

Answer (score 6):

`Thread.sleep()` makes *the current thread* sleep. This is spelled out in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29):

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep()` only makes the calling thread sleep.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep()` makes the current thread sleep; but it is bit confusing. This is why, now; the suggested way is to use [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep%28long%29) sleep method. This API got added in Java SE5 version.

```
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

Javadoc :

> Performs a `Thread.sleep` using this unit. This is a convenience method that converts time arguments into the form required by the `Thread.sleep` method.

Also you can use different units like `SECONDS`, `MILLISECONDS` etc to avoid any confusion on the unit of argument passed inside sleep method.

Comment: "This is why, now; the suggested way is to use TimeUnit sleep method." I don't know that it is the suggested way - it is an alternative way.

Comment: hmm...i should have used 'more readable' way. thanks for clarification @assylias

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual:

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds

So no, it doesn't effect all threads.

Answer (score 0):

No, only the current thread sleeps. According to the documentation:

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease
>   execution) for the specified number of milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

> Thread.sleep(x)

causes the **current thread to (sleep) suspend execution** for a **‘x ‘ ms**. This is an efficient means of making processor time available to the other threads of  your  application or other applications   on  your  system.